# Add missing hashes from one Array into another

Tags: ruby

I have two ruby Arrays. The source_array contains all my source data in form of hashes. I have a user_array that contains a subset of data that a user has selected. I need to merge/combine the two arrays to form a new result_array keeping all the hashes from the user_array and adding those hashes from the source_array that does not exist in the user_array.

Source Array:

```
   source_array = [ 
      {:category=>"truck", :make=>"ford", :model=>"F150", :notes=>""}, 
      {:category=>"truck", :make=>"ford", :model=>"F250", :notes=>""}, 
      {:category=>"truck", :make=>"ford", :model=>"F350", :notes=>""},
      {:category=>"truck", :make=>"chevy", :model=>"Silverado 1500", :notes=>""}
    ]
```

Target Array:

```
target_array = [ 
  {:category=>"truck", :make=>"ford", :model=>"F150", :notes=>"Mileage 290 miles for a full tank of gas. Shortlist for now."}
]
```

Result Array:

```
result_array = [ 
      {:category=>"truck", :make=>"ford", :model=>"F150", :notes=>""}, 
      {:category=>"truck", :make=>"ford", :model=>"F250", :notes=>""}, 
      {:category=>"truck", :make=>"ford", :model=>"F350", :notes=>""},
      {:category=>"truck", :make=>"ford", :model=>"F150", :notes=>"Mileage 290 miles for a full tank of gas. Shortlist for now."}
    ]
```

I appreciate any help you can provide!

Comment: Whar have you tried?

Comment: what you have are arrays, not hashes (btw, first have invalid syntax)

Comment: You need to edit your question to clarify what you want. Among other things, it would be helpful to show the desired result for your example. Also, it's helpful to assign variables to all input objects in your example (`for example, source_arr = [ {:category=>....}]` and `target_arr = [...]`). That way, readers can reference those variables in answers and comments without having to define them, and all readers will speak to the same variables. Two other things: change your references to "hashes" to "arrays" and change `:notes=""` to `:notes=>""` in four places.

Comment: Thank you @CarySwoveland. Updated per your request/guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given

```
source_arr =
[ 
  {:category=>"truck", :make=>"ford",  :model=>"F150", :notes=>""}, 
  {:category=>"truck", :make=>"ford",  :model=>"F250", :notes=>""}, 
  {:category=>"truck", :make=>"ford",  :model=>"F350", :notes=>""},
  {:category=>"truck", :make=>"chevy", :model=>"Silverado 1500", :notes=>""}
]

target_arr =
[ 
  {:category=>"truck", :make=>"ford", :model=>"F150",
   :notes=>"Mileage 290 miles for a full tank of gas. Shortlist for now."},
  {:category=>"truck", :make=>"ford",  :model=>"F350", :notes=>"what a beast!"}
]
```

First construct a hash with the keys that are to be matched.

```
target_hashes = target_arr.map { |h| h.reject { |k,_| k == :notes } }
  #=> [{:category=>"truck", :make=>"ford", :model=>"F150"},
  #    {:category=>"truck", :make=>"ford", :model=>"F350"}]
```

Next construct an array that contains all the hashes in `source_arr` that do not match all the keys of hashes in `target_hashes`.

```
sources_to_add = source_arr.reject { |h|
  target_hashes.include?(h.reject {|k,_| k == :notes }) }
  #=> [{:category=>"truck", :make=>"ford", :model=>"F250", :notes=>""},
  #    {:category=>"truck", :make=>"chevy", :model=>"Silverado 1500", :notes=>""}]
```

Now construct the desired array.

```
target_arr + sources_to_add
  #=> [{:category=>"truck", :make=>"ford", :model=>"F150",
  #     :notes=>"Mileage 290 miles for a full tank of gas. Shortlist for now."},
  #    {:category=>"truck", :make=>"ford", :model=>"F350",
  #     :notes=>"what a beast!"},
  #    {:category=>"truck", :make=>"ford", :model=>"F250", :notes=>""},
  #    {:category=>"truck", :make=>"chevy", :model=>"Silverado 1500",
  #     :notes=>""}]
```

if you don't want to modify `target_arr` or

```
target_arr += sources_to_add
```

if you do.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I wanted. Let me try this out now, and I will update back.